# Unidentified Hand Tool

Tags: hand-tools

The tool below appears to have been well used by someone. It has an adjustable depth guide, a micro-adjustment (second/middle knurled adjuster), replaceable bit/tip. It appears to be made for flat bottoming a hole, and I suspect there are bits to match the 16 different circumferences of the bottom of the brace. But I can’t think of what would need that flat bottom which would not have been milled to begin with. Seems a hand tool like this would be for repair rather than production.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is a gate valve reseating tool.  It makes the seat of a gate valve nice and flat so the rubber washer can make good contact.

[image]

https://www.amazon.com/valve-reseating-tool/s?k=valve+reseating+tool

Comment: Thanks. I finally remembered it late at night - it was sitting with my seat wrench. Probably have not used it in 40 years.